# ffmpeg can't change number of B-frames

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

When streaming from a source I keep receiving frames following the same pattern:
`I-frame P-frame I-frame P-frame I-frame P-frame ...`.
I tried many options and read as many questions here as I found, but I can't find a way to increse the number of P-frame or at least enable B-frames.

Mainly it seems that I should use:

```
 ffprobe rtsp://localhost/video -g 30 -bf 3 -show_frames -of csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the codec you use?

Comment: It seems it would be h264 (if there are any other h264 codec I can try them)

Comment: Are you using the `baseline` profile? Apparently it will prevent `libx264` from supporting B-frames.

Comment: I have not set it explicitly. Is there a way I could tell if it has been used?